# Windows 7 Automatically deletes necessary scanner file from \%windir%\twain_32\fjscan32\ directory

Tags: windows-7

I am at the end of my rope with this.  I've been asked to install a Fujitsu fi-5120c scanner onto a Windows 7 Pro workstation.  I downloaded the most recent driver from the Fujitsu website and run the install as Administrator (I've run it as the admin of the workstation and as domain administrator).  The installation process creates a directory \%windir%\twain_32\fjscan32\ and places into that directory a number of files.  One of those files is named FJTW32.wrp.  I've been told by Fujitsu tech support that when I plug my scanner into the workstation's USB port, their software is supposed to make a copy of that file and rename it FJTW2500.ds.  When we go through the normal install process that file does not get created.

SO, Fujitsu said, "No Problem Man!  We'll just create the file manually and you'll be fixed!"  So we manually copy FJTW32.wrp to FJTW2500.ds, reboot the computer, look to the directory expecting to see the file and IT DISAPPEARS.

We've removed antivirus from the machine thinking that maybe it was removing the file.  No joy.

Nothing I can do causes that file to **not** be deleted.  I have changed ownership and modified permissions to deny deletion, but the file just keeps getting deleted.

I have also completely disabled UAC on the machine thinking that would solve matters... but no go.

I also created a dummy file called testds.ds (a zero byte file) and placed it in that directory.  After rebooting, that file too had been removed.

I CAN, however, create file like readme.txt in that same folder, reboot the computer, and find that the txt file still exists.

Anyone? Please?!

Comment: Might be VirtualStore redirection (part of UAC), check if the file ended up in `\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows` someplace.

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that this "problem" was likely related to Fujitsu software itself, not Windows.  After uninstalling all Fujitsu software from the workstation it left the \%windir%\twain_32\fjscan32\ directory as a remnant.  I placed into that directory a file ending in the .ds extension then rebooted the machine.  After rebooting I checked the directory and found that the .ds file had NOT been deleted.  Issue with Fujitsu software.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same problem, your post was very helpful in helping me figure this out: I set the ds file to **read-only** and that prevented the Fujitsu software from deleting the file.  What Fujitsu is trying to do, is when you install the driver, your suppose to restart.  On the restart, the drivers are suppose to install as soon as you boot, when the new driver install completes, the Fujitsu software grabs the hardware ID of the scanner and matches that with the IDs that are in icScanner.id and creates your ds file.  The number of characters in the ID is 4 (0000), so if the ID is 4, then the number should read 0400 (in your example the id was 25 so 2500).

Additional info:

One of the Fujtisu's I've dealt with the wrp file was named "Fjicwrap.wrp" which the naming scheme was a little different.  Copy that file and use the same steps above accept name it FjiDS0400.wrp (FjiDS2500.wrp).  And of course set to read-only.